# Need help fixing Dynamic Position of Image JS

Tags: javascript, image, dynamic, position, trigonometry

I have been working on a JS project where a sun goes around an image in a circle, and based on its position a higher index div will change opacity to make it darker or lighter. My problem is; while at one point the Sun moved in a circle, it no longer does. I have tried many things to fix this, but to no avail. My documented code is as follows:

```
<style>
  sun{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  dark-light{
    z-index: 2;
  }

</style>
```

CSS:^     JS:v

```
<script>



  move();

  //calls move


  function move(){
   //set rot
    var rot = 180;

    var pictureToDisplay = prompt('Please insert link to picture to     display','URL Necessary to function properly, but not required. Press enter to continue.');
    //asks user to insert picture link for STATIONARY picture
    var img = document.getElementById('img');

    if (pictureToDisplay == 'URL Necessary to function properly, but not required. Press enter to continue.'){

    }else{
    img.src = pictureToDisplay;
    }
    //Sets stationary picture
    window.setInterval( function() {

      //Repeats every 75 milliseconds forever.

      var obj = document.getElementById('sun');
    // obj. is equal to id sun
      var top = (Math.sin(rot)*500)+500;
      var left = (Math.cos(rot)*500)+500;
      //uses var rot, sine, and cosine to determine moving sun position
      var toppx = top + 'px';
      var leftpx = left + 'px';
      //adds the px after those values
      obj.style.top = toppx;
      obj.style.left = leftpx;
      //attempts to set position of obj (id sun)
      var darkToLight = -0.5+(top/500);
      //determines opacity of div using var top

      //document.write(rot+' = rot : ');

      var lightDiv = document.getElementById('dark-light');
      // same as var obj, but with the div
      lightDiv.style.opacity = darkToLight;
      //sets lightDiv to opacity
      //document.write(toppx,' ,',leftpx,' : ');


    rot = (rot+0.01) % 360;
      //moves rot up by 0.01, modulate 360
    }, 75);
    //back to top of setInterval
  }


</script>
```

P.S. I know no JQuery.
Edit: The position of all is absolute, 0,0 is the top left corner of the page. I made sure not to deal with negatives. The sun should be absolute to the page, as its in nothing.

Comment: this does not help since the orientation and css of the page and sun is not given, the rotation formula works but you have to take into account the orientation (which point is (0,0)) plus how to deal with negative coordinates and how all these relate to your html layout and css styling, for example is sun position absolute and if so inside what?

Comment: Sorry, @Nikos M.  The position of all is absolute, 0,0 is the top left corner of the page. I made sure not to deal with negatives. The sun should be absolute to the page, as its in nothing.

Comment: Then you have to take accoutn of the sun dimensions (radius) plus trabslate the top-left cornert to center (by subtracting half the radius of the sun from the coords)

Comment: @Nikos M. so it would be `(Math.sin(rot)*500)+500+(obj.height/2)` ?

Comment: The polar coordi\nates given by sin and cos assume the center is at (0,0) so you need to do 2 things first move the center of the rotation to the center of rotation (i asume this to be the "earth") get the polar coordinates then translate the sun by half its radius so its center lies exactly at the polare point, remember that the css coordinates ar given by top-left corner. Finally examine css animations and css-transforms which can do same thing with much better efficiency

Comment: @Nikos M. The way I have it set up, there are never any negative numbers, and it just gets farther away and closer to (0,0), which is the top left of the page. It was working, but now its not, and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out that I apparently am not too good with css, and after adding in `style="position:absolute";` it now works fine.